# if statement in jekyll + liquid create codeblock instead of intened html tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Hey I have for each loop in Jekyll which in each increment increase the count of a variable `phdCount` which I do like this: `{% assign phdCount = phdCount | plus:1 %}`. When `phdCount == 3` is true I won't to close a boostrap row and start a new so, which I attempt to do like this:

```
{% if phdCount == 3 %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
{% endif %}
```

Which should give me closing and opening div tag in my HTML. But what I get instead is a code block in HTML containing the tags as shown: 
[image]

I have not included any custom gems or anything in `/lib`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is rendering with a code block because of the indentation/spacing.

```
{% if phdCount == 3 %}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
{% endif %}
```

should be

```
{% if phdCount == 3 %}
</div>
<div class="row">
{% endif %}
```

That will remove the code block. However, the fact that the page is thinking there could be a code block and not just treating it strictly as HTML code means that there could be something else wrong with the page. If you're in a `.md` file trying to mix in HTML, then that could be where the code block could be coming from. If you're in a `.html` file, then something else could be the issue.

Could you show the code surrounding the `{% if %}` block?

Comment: I was missing a `</div>` and it was indentation. Thanks a lot :)